# Can not pick API with google services in android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I need to test an application with Google Services. When I try to change API with Google Services in settings:
[[image: 1]]

After I press "Ok" button and go back to API settings it comes back to API without google services. Do you have any idea why?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Are you using the native emulator of Android Studio?

Comment: Using your cell phone is all right?

Comment: The problem is that I do not have cell phone with Android

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the genymotion emulator, is faster then the Android Studio emulator and have less problems.

> https://www.genymotion.com

Comment: Any other solutions? There has to be any option to turn it on.